# How to separate strings in actionscripts 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, animate-cc

I need code sample to separate a string, i'm new developer please write sample code. thanks.

This is string:

**username@gmail.com|3.705|18|0.90**

I need to separate each part between "|":

**username@gmail.com**

**3.705**

**18**

**0.90**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Sample_String: String = "username@gmail.com|3.705|18|0.90"

var VALUE1: String = Sample_String.split("|")[0];
var VALUE2: String = Sample_String.split("|")[1];
var VALUE3: String = Sample_String.split("|")[2];
var VALUE4: String = Sample_String.split("|")[3];

trace(VALUE1);
trace(VALUE2);
trace(VALUE3);
trace(VALUE4);
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output:

```
username@gmail.com
3.705
18
0.90
```

Comment: Bad in terms of performance. String.split(...) is relatively heavy operation and it is much better to do it only once and assign the resulting Array to a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` function once to create an `Array` of split `String` as below:

```
private var myString:String = "username@gmail.com|3.705|18|0.90";

var splitStringArray: Array = myString.split("|");
for each (var splitString:String in splitStringArray)
{
    trace(splitString);
}
```